# Functions in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

If I have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that belongs to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for all $p\geq 2$ including $p=\infty$, that is
$$f \in \bigcap_{p\in [2,\infty]} L^p(\mathbb{R})$$
and all the norms have the same bound, let us say that for all $p\geq 2$
$$\|f\|_p \leq C$$
and
$$\|f\|_\infty \leq C$$

Can we conclude that $f$ is also in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1< p <2$ and that 
$$\|f\|_p \leq C?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}, & |x| \geq 1\\ 1 & |x|<1. \end{cases}
$$
When $1>\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ this in $L^p$ for $p\geq 2$, but not in $L^1$, and in fact there will be $1 < q < 2$ so that $f\in L^p$ for $q < p$, but $f \notin L^p$ for $1 \leq p \leq q$. The $L^p$-norms are bounded by the $L^p$-norm of the smallest $p$ so that the $L^p$-norm is finite.

Comment: aha sure.. I was trying identically the same function as  you but $1/x$, so it didn't work. I see I see! thanks a lot!

Comment: A general tip: functions of the form $1/|x|^\alpha$ are among the first things you should consider when trying to reason about different $L^p$ spaces. Practically all of the information that differentiates $L^p$ spaces is contained in these examples.